# Is a thread from ThreadPool always available right after return in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, executorservice

I need to take a thread from the ThreadPoolExecutor if one is free, otherwise I save the data for later (the ThreadPool has a 0-sized queue).
In the following code:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(n, n,
            60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
Object lock = new Object();

// ...

executor.execute(() -> {
    // ...
    synchronized(lock) {
        // ...
        if (...) {
            return;
        }
    }
    // ...
});

// ...

synchronized(lock) {
    if (executor.getCorePoolSize() - executor.getActiveCount() > 0) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Can I be certain that the thread is considered not active once return statement is reached ? Can the process pause for any reason leading to the situation where:

- return is done, thus lock is free (but thread still active)
- we check for free threads and find out there is none
- thread's run() method terminates (thread is now free)

In other words, can it take time for the process to go from the end of the first synchronized block's return to the end of the Runnable (even if there is no statement in-between) ?

Comment: I don't think there's enough code here for us to say for sure.  Please show us which thread pool you're using and how it gets initialized, and also knowing what `lock` is and why we should care about it is handy as well.  I don't think anything at all about a thread pool is "guaranteed" but normally I'd expect a thread to be available after an previous task exits.  But that's a weird way to use a thread pool.  It sounds like you're basically busy-waiting on the thread pool availability.  Which is... weird.

Comment: I will add those info asap.I am not waiting on the thread pool availability, only saving some data that will be handled the next time we check for a free thread and there is one, for a bacthed processing this time.

Comment: If you want returned data from a thread, look at the `Future` class and its `get()` method to return data from a thread.  If you're running a batch process, I'd 1. Use a new thread pool to avoid conflicts, or 2. Use a special thread pool just for batch processes, or 3. Just run the batch process in the thread you already have.

Comment: It is depends on the thread poll type. It can be fixed or cashed thread pool. Poll exist until you are call for shutdown.

Comment: I'll think about those ideas thanks.